# JavaFX + Spring (JDBC & @SpringBootApplication & @Autowired & @Transactional)

Tags: spring, javafx, spring-boot, autowired, transactional

I'd like to use JavaFX with DB access using Spring JDBC. However I'm completely new to Spring and it seems that I cannot fully understand it's features, especially transactions handling...

I've added following dependencies to my project:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

... and I want to use Spring transactions handling mechanism when GUI application is doing it's operations on DB. As I understand it, following code should:

- initialize and start JavaFX application - create and show GUI wireframe
- initialize Spring
- configure and inject JdbcTemplate dependency
- start transaction handling mechanism and begin transaction
- use jdbcTemplate object to create 5 entries in DB in `for loop`
- simulate error (by throwing `RuntimeException`)
- revert operations on DB
- exit

So, summing up: when `RuntimeException` is thrown in method annotated as `@Transactional` that should revert all entries already created by this method before application quits, isn't it?

However all created entries stay permanently in DB (I can see them there after application quits). So first of all - am I understanding correctly how these transactions should work? If so, then how to make them actually work as I expect?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTransactional extends Application {
    private Pane viewPane;

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    /** application.properties:
     spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
     spring.datasource.username = db_username
     spring.datasource.password = username123
     */
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringTransactional.class);
        springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        viewPane = assembleView(primaryStage);

        try {
            db_transaction_test();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Platform.exit();
    }

    private Pane assembleView(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox rootPane = new VBox();
        rootPane.setSpacing(10);
        rootPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        rootPane.setStyle("-fx-base: #84a7ad;");
        rootPane.getChildren().add(new Label("GUI goes here."));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        return rootPane;
    }

    @Transactional
    private void db_transaction_test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                int entry_name = getEntryId("entry_" + i);
                System.out.println("Created entry id=" + entry_name);
            } catch (DaoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == 5) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Testing data upload procedure break.");
            }
        }
    }

    /** DB creation and schema:
     CREATE DATABASE db_name;
     CREATE USER db_username;

     USE db_name;
     GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO db_username;

     SET PASSWORD FOR spz = PASSWORD('username123');
     FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

     CREATE TABLE Entry (
     entry_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name   TEXT NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (entry_ID)
     );
     */
    private int getEntryId(String entryName) throws DaoException {
        List<DbEntry> dbEntries = retrieveEntriesFor(entryName);

        if (dbEntries.size() == 1) {
            return dbEntries.get(0).getEntry_ID();
        } else if (dbEntries.size() == 0) {
            String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Entry (name) VALUES (?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sqlInsert, entryName);
            dbEntries = retrieveEntriesFor(entryName);
            if (dbEntries.size() == 1) {
                return dbEntries.get(0).getEntry_ID();
            } else {
                throw new DaoException("Invalid results amount received after creating new (" + dbEntries.size() + ") when getting entry for name: " + entryName);
            }
        } else {
            throw new DaoException("Invalid results amount received (" + dbEntries.size() + ") when getting entry for name: " + entryName);
        }
    }

    private List<DbEntry> retrieveEntriesFor(String entryName) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE name=?;", (ResultSet result, int rowNum) -> unMarshal(result), entryName);
    }

    private DbEntry unMarshal(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        DbEntry dbEntry = new DbEntry();
        dbEntry.setEntry_ID(result.getInt("entry_ID"));
        dbEntry.setName(result.getString("name"));
        return dbEntry;
    }

    public class DbEntry {
        private int entry_ID;
        private String name;

        int getEntry_ID() { return entry_ID; }
        void setEntry_ID(int entry_ID) { this.entry_ID = entry_ID; }
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }

    private class DaoException extends Throwable {
        DaoException(String err_msg) { super(err_msg); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing it seems that creating separate Spring component `EntryDao` works (thanks James_D) but only if `db_transaction_test` annotaded with `@Transactional` is in that class - OPTION A in code below.

But what I'm really interested in is OPTION B - when `db_transaction_test` annotaded with `@Transactional` is in another class. This is because DAO class does not (and should not) know about DB-unrealted issues that are the reason of reverting a bunch of previous DB operations. This information comes from other 'controllers' which failrues must not cause data integrity issues. So in the example below `SpringTransactional` should be the only one that can throw this particular `RuntimeException("Testing data upload procedure break.");` (as an example of real-life system/environment issues). However as stacktrace at the end shows - transaction is not initalized there.

So is there a way to get it work as I need with Spring `@Transactional` (aka. declarative transactions) or only with manual (aka. programmatic) Spring transactions control? And if this is the only way then how to configure `DataSourceTransactionManager` while using `@SpringBootApplication` for "auto-configuration" and `@Autowired` for `jdbcTemplate` object?

Main class:

```
package tmp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import tmp.dao.EntryDao;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTransactional extends Application {
    private Pane viewPane;

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Autowired
    private EntryDao dao;

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringTransactional.class);
        springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception { springContext.close(); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        viewPane = assembleView(primaryStage);

        // OPTION A:
        try {
            dao.db_transaction_test();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // OPTION B:
        try {
            db_transaction_test();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Transactional
    private void db_transaction_test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                int entry_name = dao.getEntryId("entry_" + i);
                System.out.println("Created entry id=" + entry_name);
            } catch (EntryDao.DaoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == 5) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Testing data upload procedure break.");
            }
        }
    }

    private Pane assembleView(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox rootPane = new VBox();
        rootPane.setSpacing(10);
        rootPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        rootPane.setStyle("-fx-base: #84a7ad;");
        rootPane.getChildren().add(new Label("GUI goes here."));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        return rootPane;
    }
}
```

EntryDao class:

```
package tmp.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * DB creation and schema:
 * CREATE DATABASE db_name;
 * CREATE USER db_username;
 * <p>
 * USE db_name;
 * GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO db_username;
 * <p>
 * SET PASSWORD FOR spz = PASSWORD('username123');
 * FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 * <p>
 * CREATE TABLE Entry (
 * entry_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 * name   TEXT NOT NULL,
 * <p>
 * PRIMARY KEY (entry_ID)
 * );
 */
@Component
public class EntryDao {
    /**
     * application.properties:
     * spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     * spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
     * spring.datasource.username = db_username
     * spring.datasource.password = username123
     */
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void db_transaction_test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                int entry_name = getEntryId("entry_" + i);
                System.out.println("Created entry id=" + entry_name);
            } catch (EntryDao.DaoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == 5) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Testing data upload procedure break.");
            }
        }
    }

    public int getEntryId(String entryName) throws DaoException {
        List<DbEntry> dbEntries = retrieveEntriesFor(entryName);

        if (dbEntries.size() == 1) {
            return dbEntries.get(0).getEntry_ID();
        } else if (dbEntries.size() == 0) {
            String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Entry (name) VALUES (?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sqlInsert, entryName);
            dbEntries = retrieveEntriesFor(entryName);
            if (dbEntries.size() == 1) {
                return dbEntries.get(0).getEntry_ID();
            } else {
                throw new DaoException("Invalid results amount received after creating new (" + dbEntries.size() + ") when getting entry for name: " + entryName);
            }
        } else {
            throw new DaoException("Invalid results amount received (" + dbEntries.size() + ") when getting entry for name: " + entryName);
        }
    }

    private List<DbEntry> retrieveEntriesFor(String entryName) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE name=?;", (ResultSet result, int rowNum) -> unMarshal(result), entryName);
    }

    private DbEntry unMarshal(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        DbEntry dbEntry = new DbEntry();
        dbEntry.setEntry_ID(result.getInt("entry_ID"));
        dbEntry.setName(result.getString("name"));
        return dbEntry;
    }

    public class DbEntry {
        private int entry_ID;
        private String name;

        int getEntry_ID() { return entry_ID; }
        void setEntry_ID(int entry_ID) { this.entry_ID = entry_ID; }
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }

    public class DaoException extends Throwable { DaoException(String err_msg) { super(err_msg); } }
}
```

STACKTRACE

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-01-10 09:41:48.902  INFO 1860 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on alwihasolaptop with PID 1860 (started by alwi in C:\alwi\Workspace_SPZ\GCodeClient)
2017-01-10 09:41:48.905  INFO 1860 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-01-10 09:41:48.965  INFO 1860 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@18660f3: startup date [Tue Jan 10 09:41:48 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-01-10 09:41:49.917  INFO 1860 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-01-10 09:41:49.927  INFO 1860 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 1.384 seconds (JVM running for 1.969)
Created entry id=73
Created entry id=74
Created entry id=75
Created entry id=76
Created entry id=77
Created entry id=78
java.lang.RuntimeException: Testing data upload procedure break.
    at tmp.dao.EntryDao.db_transaction_test(EntryDao.java:53)
    at tmp.dao.EntryDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a857b433.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at tmp.dao.EntryDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84e8651e.db_transaction_test(<generated>)
    at tmp.SpringTransactional.start(SpringTransactional.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Created entry id=73
Created entry id=74
Created entry id=75
Created entry id=76
Created entry id=77
Created entry id=78
2017-01-10 09:41:50.545  INFO 1860 --- [lication Thread] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@18660f3: startup date [Tue Jan 10 09:41:48 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
java.lang.RuntimeException: Testing data upload procedure break.
    at tmp.SpringTransactional.db_transaction_test(SpringTransactional.java:71)
    at tmp.SpringTransactional.start(SpringTransactional.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-01-10 09:41:50.546  INFO 1860 --- [lication Thread] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

SOLUTION:

Best solution I've found so far is using Spring `TransactionTemplate` together with additional callback class:

```
package tmp.dao;

public abstract class DbTransactionTask { public abstract void executeTask(); }
```

and in `SpringTransactional` class `db_transaction_test()` method (note that `@Transactional` is out):

```
private void db_transaction_test() {
    DbTransactionTask dbTask = new DbTransactionTask() {
        @Override
        public void executeTask() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    int entry_name = dao.getEntryId("entry_" + i);
                    System.out.println("Created entry id=" + entry_name);
                } catch (EntryDao.DaoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (i == 5) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Testing data upload procedure break.");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    dao.executeTransactionWithoutResult(dbTask);
}
```

`EntryDao` class requires this additional code:

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

public void executeTransactionWithoutResult(DbTransactionTask dbTask) {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            dbTask.executeTask();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So the typical set up is that you mark transactions on your business tier methods, and inject your DAO into the business tier whose methods then invoke it. But the actual answer to your question is the same no matter how you structure it: `@Transactional` *only works on Spring-managed beans*. In your question you were trying to use it on an object that was created externally to Spring.

Comment: And what about: `springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);` in the question? It was able to inject `@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` although it's "on an object that was created externally to Spring" as you put it...

Comment: Correct: that basically tells the application context to inject all known beans into fields annotated `@Autowire` for the object you pass in (this in this case). But it doesn't - can't possibly, in fact - replace that object in memory with a proxy object. So while it injects beans, it cannot change the behavior of the existing object. So your `db_transaction_test()` method still does exactly what you coded it to do, no more and no less. It can't magically decorate the implementation of a method belonging to an existing object with the transactional behavior.

Comment: The thing I like about spring is that it's reasonably easy to see how it all works and consequently exactly what it's doing. There's no "slight of hand". So it's pretty obvious what the `autowireBean(...)` method does: takes the provided object, iterates through its fields and `set..()` methods looking for annotations, and sets the fields or invokes the set methods when it has a bean that matches. It's all just plain and standard Java, even though it's highly useful. But (obviously, surely) you can't change the implementation of a method belonging to an object already in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Transactions in Spring work the same way as AOP works in Spring: when you request a bean from Spring which has methods marked as transactional, you actually receive a proxy to that bean whose implementation of the transactional methods "decorates" the implementation you provide in your implementation class. In brief, the implementation of the method in the proxy class begins a transaction, then invokes the method defined in your implementation class, then either commits or rolls the transaction back.

So I *think* the issue is that the `SpringTransactional` instance is not created by the Spring application context, but is created by the JavaFX startup process (i.e. it is created by the JavaFX framework when you call `Application.launch()`). Consequently, Spring cannot create the proxy object that implements the transactional behavior.

Try factoring the database functionality into a separate class that is spring-managed, and injecting an instance of that into your application class. I.e. do something like

```
// Note: I'm only familiar with "traditional" Spring, not Spring boot. 
// Not sure if this annotation is picked up by Spring boot, you may need to 
// make some changes to the config or something to get this working.
@Component
public class DAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;

    @Transactional
    private void db_transaction_test() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then in your application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTransactional extends Application {
    private Pane viewPane;

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Autowired
    private DAO dao ;

    // ...

     @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        viewPane = assembleView(primaryStage);

        try {
            dao.db_transaction_test();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Platform.exit();
    }  

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply but as I've stated above I'm completely new to Spring and wanted some solution without learning whole 'old' way of configuration (with its own issues) and therefore - as in the subject - using `@SpringBootApplication` is one of main parts of this question and what I'm really interested in...

Comment: @alwi I think you completely missed the point here. The `// ...` above are just supposed to indicate that you include the existing code, i.e. this is still using Spring Boot. You just need to configure the DAO as a spring managed bean (however that happens in Spring Boot). Nowhere in my answer do I say "don't use Spring Boot". The point is that `@Transactional` *only works on spring-managed beans*: it doesn't magically work if you use it on methods in objects that are created externally to Spring (whether you use Spring Boot or "classic" Spring Framework).

Comment: I get what your'e saying. It's obvious that // ... means all the business logic. In previous message I was refering to your comment "you may need 
 make some changes to the config or something to get this working" together with "I'm only familiar with /traditional/ Spring, not Spring boot.".

Comment: @alwi By "to get this working" I meant "to get this working in Spring Boot". Sorry for the confusion there. I don't know if Spring Boot will create the bean simply because the class is annotated, or if further config is needed. I assume you can figure that out yourself, as a Spring Boot user.